# how to cancel a progressDialog using back button?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-progressbar

I'm displaying a progressDialog when the program is fetching some data from internet (using the AsyncTask). It seems that back button is disabled when the progressDialog is being displayed.

How should I cancel the progressDialog using the back button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void     setCancelable(boolean flag)
```

Sets whether this dialog is cancelable with the BACK key.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the back button Functionality and can use the code given below to cancel the dialog box-

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if(Dialog.isShowing())
{
Dialog.dismiss();
}
super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like the following,

```
progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
```